# Json_encode and json_decode to textarea - line breaks problem

Tags: json, textarea

i had a problem with line breaks in textarea
i have a form with textarea like this:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<label><textarea name="content_stream"></textarea>
</form>
```

i insert the value to the db like this:

```
$content_streams = $_POST["content_stream"];
$stream = !empty($content_streams) ? json_encode( $content_streams, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ) : "";
...insert to db...
```

i printed the $stream variable and he was like this: (because i inserted line break in the textarea)

```
1\r\n2
```

but when i fetch the result like this:

```
$content_streams = $db["content_stream"];
    $stream = !empty($content_streams) ? json_decode( $content_streams, true ) : array();
```

i got json parse error because the \r\n of the line break. without the linebreak its working.

what can i do?

Comment: solved by: $stream = str_replace("\\r\\n", "\\\\n", $stream);

Answer (score 0):

If the value is sent from IOS Device add the below line in php

```
$json = str_replace("\n","\\n",$json);
```

and then do the json decode with the new value

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
```